# Oracle db. How to get a result set of unique values of pretty much arbitrary amount of columns of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Having this column structure

```
Id, col_1, col_2, col_3
1    A      A      B
2    B      B      B
3    C      C      D
```

Is it possible to get one-column output with unique values?

```
res_column
 A
 B
 C
 D
```

What I've already tried:

1. Union seems doable only in case there are 2 to 3 columns, which is not the case.
2. I've found a pivot/unpivot, but I didn't really grasp it.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz This is Oracle. Will add it to the description. Thank you.

Comment: You do need to grasp unpivot (in this case). The operation of converting multiple columns into a single one is called "unpivoting". You can do it with UNION ALL (which does work for any number of columns), but that is just a very rudimentary way to implement UNPIVOT by hand. Even if you do it that way (and don't learn the syntax of UNPIVOT), you still need to understand what "unpivot" means at the logical level. And then it will be very easy to grasp the syntax of UNPIVOT in Oracle SQL.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you for explaining the logic. It's awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
  sample_inputs (id, col_1, col_2, col_3) as (
    select 1, 'A', 'A', 'B' from dual union all
    select 2, 'B', 'B', 'B' from dual union all
    select 3, 'C', 'C', 'D' from dual
  )
select  distinct res_column
from    sample_inputs
unpivot (res_column for col in (col_1, col_2, col_3))
order   by res_column    ---   if needed
;

RES_COLUMN
----------
A
B
C
D
```

If you must handle `null` also, you can do so with the `include nulls` option to `unpivot`. Without this option, the query above will still work - it will just ignore (discard, exclude) all `null` from the unpivoted columns.

```
with
  sample_inputs (id, col_1, col_2, col_3) as (
    select 1, 'A' , 'A' , 'B'  from dual union all
    select 2, 'B' , 'B' , 'B'  from dual union all
    select 3, 'C' , 'C' , 'D'  from dual union all
    select 4, null, null, null from dual
  )
select  distinct res_column
from    sample_inputs
unpivot include nulls (res_column for col in (col_1, col_2, col_3))
order   by res_column    ---   if needed
;


RES_COLUMN
----------
A
B
C
D
 
 
(five rows selected)
```

Note that the last result has **five** rows, not four; the last value is `null`, which is invisible, but if you run the query in an editor that shows you the number of rows (or if you use an option to show `null` as **`<null>`** or such), then you will see it.

NOTE: You can't make this "generic" in plain SQL; the number of columns to unpivot, and their names, must be hard-coded in the query. If you need a "generic" solution you will need to use dynamic SQL; that is a much more advanced topic, and certainly not appropriate if you don't even grasp static `unpivot` yet.